# Boostrap main table cells shrink when text in nested table is too long

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I created a Bootstrap table with 6 columns and 2 rows (without counting the header); the first row contains 6 cells with some text and buttons, and the second row contains 1 cell with a colspan of 6, and contains two Bootstrap tooglable tabs. The second tab (called "Links") contains a table with one row and two columns.

When the text in the first column of the nested table is too long, the cells of the first row of the main table shrink, breaking buttons layout. This happens in Firefox and also in Chrome (cells shrink less in Chrome), but not in Safari. When the text is short enough, the cells don't shrink.

I tested it on a MacBook Pro 13" with latest Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the code and the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0owjypxn/2/embedded/result/). You have to run the jsfiddle in fullscreen and have at least a 13" screen.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Some very random content</td>
          <td> <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" target="_blank" href="">M</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" target="_blank" href="">L</a>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" target="_blank" href="">Website</a>

          </td>
          <td>A description - A description A description...</td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-md" role="group" aria-label="...">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Blacklist</button>
                <button class="see-more btn btn-default">See more</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-md">Button 3</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class=" btn btn-default btn-md">Some long text</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li role="presentation" class="general-tab active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#general">General</a>

              </li>
              <li role="presentation" class="links-tab"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#links">Links</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="general">Some content</div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="links">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <table class="table">
                      <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-4">Col 1</th>
                        <th class="col-md-4">Col 2</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-4">This text shrinks the parent table columns. This text shrinks the parent table columns. This text shrinks the parent table columns. This text shrinks the parent table columns.</td>
                        <td class="col-md-4">This is some random content. This is some random content. This is some random content</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell width resizes based on the content of other cells in the table.  If a row has too much content to display on a single row it may cause elements of some cells to wrap, depending on a cell's ability to wrap.

If you do not want your buttons to wrap, I suggest giving the parent cell a minimum width (e.g. `<td style="min-width: 160px">`.  I have updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0owjypxn/3/) with this answer.

Comment: Hello, this does not fix the resize of some main table cells. See https://jsfiddle.net/0owjypxn/4/embedded/result/ . When you display the inner table by clicking on the "Links" tab, the cells of the main table which don't have a fixed width still shrink.

Comment: Ah, now I see.  I was able to reproduce the problem in Firefox (but not Chrome for some reason). I do not know for sure why this is happening, but I suspect that the browser is trying to re-adjust the main table's column widths based on what it sees as a large amount of content in the inner table (which is represented in the main table as a single cell). You can fix this by setting that cell's width to 100%. Here is another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0owjypxn/6/embedded/result/) update.

Comment: That's awesome! I don't really understand why setting the cell's width to 100% makes it work but thanks anyway!